# Place text on top of bibliography page

Tags: bibliographies, page-breaking

I would like to include a quote at the top of the first page of my bibliography section.

```
\newenvironment{wittyquote}
{\color{darkgray} \begin{addmargin}[6cm]{0cm} \begin{footnotesize}}
{ \end{footnotesize} \end{addmargin} \bigskip }
```

However, the bibliography is automatically started on a new page. How can I make this work?

```
% Bibliography

\label{app:bibliography} % Reference the bibliography elsewhere with \autoref{app:bibliography}

\manualmark
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\bibname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\bibname}}
\refstepcounter{dummy}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{\beforebibskip}} % Place the bibliography slightly below the rest of the document content in the table of contents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\tocEntry{\bibname}}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\begin{wittyquote}
You can stand on the shoulders of giants. Or a big enough pile of dwarfs. Works either way.
-- Discordian wisdom
\end{wittyquote}

\begin{footnotesize}
\bibliography{Bibliography}
\end{footnotesize}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you didn't tell us your used document class I can only guess.

Depending on the used document class and that it seems you want to use BibTeX there are two possibilities:

1. You can use package `natbib`.  Then you can use command `\bibpreamble`.  Please see the following MWE-1.
2. If you use KOMA-Script, for example class `scrartcl`, you can use the KOMA-Sript command `\setbibpreamble`. Please see the following MWE-2.
3. Using `biblatex` is the third possibility, shown by the answer of @Daniel.

So you do not need your environment `wittyquote`, just use the predefined commands named above.

For both following MWEs I used package `filecontents` to have TeX code and Bib file concatenated to one compilable MWE.

MWE-1:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
article{einstein,
  author  = {Albert Einstein},
  title   = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German}) 
             [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
  journal = {Annalen der Physik},
  volume  = {322},
  number  = {10},
  pages   = {891--921},
  year    = {1905},
  DOI     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004},
}
@misc{mozart:KV183,
  author  = {Mozart, Wolfgang Amadeus},
  title   = {Sinfonie g-Moll},
  year    = {1773},
  address = {Salzburg},
  note    = {New K{\"o}chelverzeichnis Nr. 183, old version Nr. 25; 
             Erster Satz: Allegro con brio, Zweiter Satz: Andante, 
             Dritter Satz: Menuetto, Vierter Satz: Allegro},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\renewcommand\bibpreamble{\itshape This is the preambel for the bibliography\par\normalfont}


\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{Goossens} and \cite{adams}.

\nocite{*} % to test all bib entrys
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: result of mwe-1]

MWE-2 for KOMA-Script:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
article{einstein,
  author  = {Albert Einstein},
  title   = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German}) 
             [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
  journal = {Annalen der Physik},
  volume  = {322},
  number  = {10},
  pages   = {891--921},
  year    = {1905},
  DOI     = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004},
}
@misc{mozart:KV183,
  author  = {Mozart, Wolfgang Amadeus},
  title   = {Sinfonie g-Moll},
  year    = {1773},
  address = {Salzburg},
  note    = {New K{\"o}chelverzeichnis Nr. 183, old version Nr. 25; 
             Erster Satz: Allegro con brio, Zweiter Satz: Andante, 
             Dritter Satz: Menuetto, Vierter Satz: Allegro},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{scrartcl}

\setbibpreamble{\itshape This is the preambel for the bibliography with KOMA-Script\par\normalfont}


\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{Goossens} and \cite{adams}.

\nocite{*} % to test all bib entrys
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: result of mwe-2]

Answer (score 7):

Is the use bibtex mandatory? If not, you can use biblatex which allows to print arbitrary text at the beginning of the bibliography using the optional `prenote` option of the `\printbibliography` command.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography}

\defbibnote{wittyquote}{<your code here>}

\begin{document}

\cite{<cite something>}

\printbibliography[prenote=wittyquote]

\end{document}
```